# Merge issues in GIT - File changes which are in a Merge commit vanished from a branch after a commit

Tags: git, version-control, merge, atlassian-sourcetree

We have a branch called **BranchMaster**. We used to downmerge the code from the same to another branch called **BranchDev**.

Recently We have done downmerge from **BranchMaster** to **BranchDev**. In the merge commit, it has lots of file changes. After which, lots of commit happened in the branch **BranchDev**. One of those commit is a merge commit with another commit done by someone else in my team. After the last merge commit, All the file changes which are in the first merge commit is vanished. I am not sure why/how.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Use `git blame --reverse <old_commit>..<new commit> <name of file>` in case there were files that were deleted.

To find deleted lines, if you are aware how they were you can use `git log -S <deleted string> <filename>`

Using `git reflog` is also an option but it will only help in finding the deleted commits. The code deletion as part of new commit is not same as dropping a commit. You should check the reflog entries have not expired or cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gitk` or `sourcetree` to check which commit was responsible for the deletion of files.

Also, you can undo any commit at any point of time. Do the following.

```
git reflog
```

This will give you a list of heads of the commits made. You can revert any commit by typing the following command.

```
git reset --hard HEAD@<i>
```